# First and last name buffered reader giving me troubles

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I've fixed many other issues but after fixing one that I thought was the last error, I came a Null pointer exception.

```
package com.Text.Scanner.java;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TextScanner {
    public static void main(String ...args) throws IOException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter names for parsing");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0;i<=input.length();i++) {
            names.add(input.substring(0, input.indexOf(",")));
            input = input.substring(input.indexOf(",")+1);
        }
        System.out.println(names);
        // handles the string import to arraylist

        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));
            //finds file
            String line = reader.readLine();
            //reads line
            while (line != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++) {
                    if (line.contains(names.get(i))) {
                        //gets name from array to scan line for
                        System.out.println(line.substring(4, line.indexOf(names.get(i)) + names.get(i).length()));
                        //controls length
                        line = reader.readLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            reader.close();
           }
                catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The goal here is to scan each line for a name (first and last) then print the number aside their name on the text file.

first line: 1234 Billy Smith

second line: 5678 John Smith

what you input: Billy Smith,John Smith,

The point of it is to scan the file for the list of first and last names in an arraylist and then output the numbers and name. The program works if I go in order in the whole list, but if I don't then it gives me this. I have tried to put reader.reset() if the if statement finds a match and then if it doesn't it reads another line, but that doesn't work

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:426)
    at com.Text.Scanner.java.TextScanner.main(TextScanner.java:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= line.length(); i++) {
                if (line.contains(names.get(i))) {
```

So basically i goes from O to line.length() (number of char in the line) and you use it to accces your names with name.get(i) that absolutely no reason to be the same size (it is more the number of lines on the first line)

But why don't you debug your code ? The error you got says the error is in TestScanner line 32 calling the method get. It already say where the error !

You could even rerun that program with the debugger, and ask it to stop when an exception is raised so it would stop exactly at the right place and you be able to look at the various variables.